# Compare Attribute Not Working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have password and confirm password fields with compare attribute but it's bugged? tried everything updated everything via NuGet package manager the password is still not matching even if i input '123456', wonder what should i do?

[image]

```
  public class AccountsViewModel
    {
        public class Register
        {
            [Required]
            public string Username { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Compare("Password")]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        }

    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,username,password")] AccountsViewModel.Register viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        account account = new account();
        db.accounts.Add(account).username = viewModel.Username;
        db.accounts.Add(account).password = viewModel.Password;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View

```
@model trainingmvc.Models.AccountsViewModel.Register

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Accounts", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Web Config

```
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Bundles

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Comment: Turn off client validation, and check what is set on properties `Password` and `ConfirmPassword` when binding in the time of post back.

Comment: i'm sorry but how do i do that? im kinda of new to web dev.

Comment: Does it actually make it to the server code, or does it get rejected on the client when you debug?  If it makes it to the server it might be because you're not binding the confirm password field.  Try making [Bind(Include = "id,username,password")] this [Bind(Include = "id,username,password,confirmpassword")]

Comment: i set a breakpoint on my controller and it does not hit that break point so im guessing it failing on client side.

Comment: Hmm.  I have basically the same setup with no issues.  If you remove the datatype attribute and verify that the contents are the same does it still cause a problem?

Comment: yes, this is giving me headache, can't proceed on my project 
http://i.imgur.com/TNbmAu1.jpg?1 inputted 123456 on same textbox
result:
http://i.imgur.com/73nI8e4.jpg?1

Comment: I noticed your View code does match what is rendered in your pictures. Are you sure you are looking at the correct view?

Comment: yes i just cut the enabled on my first picture.

Comment: @Nevi Well the .cshtml you posted on here doesn't show an Enabled dropdown list.  The submit button in your pictures says Create and in your .cshtml it says "Register".  So that leads me to believe you are actually using a different view .cshtml file.

Comment: oh yeah, basically i've created another project for testing and the pictures i uploaded is from that.. so the view in the post is the view in my main project.

Comment: @Nevi I created a brand new Mvc 5 project and the Registration functionality works as expected. So you had to have made a change either on the View or Model that is causing the issue. I can't tell though because you didn't post the actual code you are using.

Comment: @ertdiddy can i download your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POST method has a `[Bind]` attribute

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,username,password")] AccountsViewModel.Register viewModel)
```

which excludes the models `ConfirmPassword` property from binding, therefore its value of it is `null` which is invalid (it does not match the value of `Password`) so a `ModelState` error is added.

`AccountsViewModel` is a view model and a view model should never need a `Bind` attribute (because a view model only contains properties that are edited in the view). Just remove the attribute so all properties are bound and you model will be valid.

Comment: But the OP said *"I set a breakpoint on my controller and it does not hit that break point so im guessing it failing on client side"*.